# What do you call somebody who brings forth change?

Tags: synonyms

Looking for a word for a body or group of people who are the initial/prominent cause of a change. For some reason my mind keeps going to angels in the bible? I think there may be a phrase used to describe angels as some kind of bringer forth of change or judgment. Unsure. The _____ of change.

Please help. My mind is drawing a blank and I've been googling for 15 minutes and have found nothing.

Comment: Got it guys, it was harbinger

Comment: A *harbinger* signals change; it does not bring forth change itself.

Comment: Not sure about the angels part, but there is "harbinger", which can mean something portending a future event, or "2a : one that initiates a major change : a person or thing that originates or helps open up a new activity, method, or technology : pioneer" The reason I brought this up is that Merriam-Webster has one definition of "angel" as "messenger" or "harbinger".

Comment: Can I ask, why did you think of angels? I'm curious. I understand angels usually come to tell of an imminent event, but I don't see them as described in the definition I quoted in my comment, ie., one that initiates a major change.

Comment: I would have said "cashier".

Answer (score 3):

I have always used the word [**catalyst**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catalyst):

> **2** : an agent that provokes or speeds significant change or action
>   // That waterway became the *catalyst* of the area's industrialization.
>   // He was the *catalyst* in the native uprising.

In your sentence:

> The catalyst of change.

Answer (score 1):

The word that comes to my mind is **[harbinger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbinger)**:

> one that initiates a major change : a person or thing that originates or helps open up a new activity, method, or technology : PIONEER

It has a literary feel to it and was used (in the “messenger” sense) in at least [one translation](https://biblehub.com/jps/isaiah/41.htm) of the Bible.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary defines it other way around. [Link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/harbinger)

Comment: @ubihatt whilst your point is taken, it was not an accident that Tolkien had Gandalf called 'Storm crow' or blamed for those messages and portents he sought to spread knowledge of, nor is the existence of the phrase 'shoot the messenger.'  Those examples yet don't cover the concept of predestination or prophecy, both of which characterize systems (and modes of thought) in which a harbinger is indeed a necessary actor between one state and another, being then equivalent in some view with an agent of change.

Comment: further of course, (but to a different objection) one wasp's doom is another insect's wish fulfilment.

Comment: This definition seems to invoke the strong Sapir-Whorf hypothesis (herald = agent of change).

Answer (score 0):

I appear to possess that talent or to be that person in people's life. Although I've been referred to by many names , I've long settled on the label of a Reformer.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably searching for the word "***herald***". The word "*harbinger*" seems to carry a negative connotation.

They acted as a **herald** of change.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/herald

Comment: The downvote was perhaps because (unlike Laurel's 'harbinger' answer) no sense of change ensuing from the news is denoted by 'herald'.

Comment: Also, the dismissal of harbinger needs evidence. While I typically associate harbingers with doom, most of [Merriam-Webster's examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbinger) are more benign: "harbinger of spring", "the great legal harbinger of the New Deal revolution", "the harbingers of peace to a hitherto distracted … people"